# OutOfRange exception when selecting data from SQL table in DATAGRIDVIEW

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am trying to create a Winforms app where I store info in a database and view them (datagridview) using SQL. I am attempting to make it so that I can pull out data from a selected row and be able to modify it later but I am getting an error. I can view the data from SQL just fine in the table but when trying to get selected row data from SQL table to display in textboxes the following exception appears :

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Arg_ParamName_Name'

C# code :

```
private void MemberSDGV_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    NomTb.Text = MemberSDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    PrenomTb.Text = MemberSDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    AgeTb.Text = MemberSDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
    AddressTb.Text = MemberSDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[13].Value.ToString();
    EmailTb.Text = MemberSDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[14].Value.ToString();
    gsmpTb.Text = MemberSDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
    gsmmTb.Text = MemberSDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[12].Value.ToString();
    gsmTb.Text = MemberSDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Loop through all rows and cells instead of hardcoding the index

Comment: Consider setting the DataSource of the DataGridView to a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) where the BindingSource.DataSource is where you are reading your data. To get the selected row use the [Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.current?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property of the BindingSource, cast to the proper type and access the row data

Comment: Error message tells you, that you are trying to access a field from an array that does not exist. E.g.: `SelectedRows[0]` if no row is selected (probably not your error) or that there are no Cells with your hardcoded indexes, e.g.: `Cells[14]`. Do you have 15 cells in your datagridview (15 because zero index based)?

Comment: I have 23 cells, using RowIndex (as @Muller-Nico pointed out in an answer) from DataGridViewCellEventArgs fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no selected row.
Use the RowIndex from DataGridViewCellEventArgs instead.

```
NomTb.Text = MemberSDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
```

[https://learn.microsoft.com/.../selected-cells-rows-and-columns-datagridview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/selected-cells-rows-and-columns-datagridview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

column headers in DGV are also cells, so clicking on the header "row" results in RowIndex being -1. Include the following code to avoid exceptions:

```
if (e.RowIndex < 0)
{
    return;
}
```